# Send EOS to pipeline containing webrtcbin and appsrc

Tags: gstreamer

I have a pipeline that receives from an application a video stream using `appsrc` and streams that stream to a WebRTC client. At the same time, the pipeline attempts to save the video to a file (as MP4 but could also be Matroska etc) in a separate branch using the `tee` command. The pipeline is created programmatically using `gst_parse_launch` and looks as follows:

```
webrtcbin bundle-policy=max-bundle name=myserver stun-server=stun://global.stun.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp 
appsrc name=TextureSource-1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc name=VideoEncoder-1 tune=zerolatency 
speed-preset=superfast ! tee name=t ! queue ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! 
filesink location=capture.mp4 t. ! queue ! rtph264pay ! 
application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! myserver.
```

I can receive the stream without issues on my WebRTC client but the problem is, the saved MP4 file is mostly unplayable. Somehow, I can only play the file using [ffplay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html) which plays it at approximately twice the speed of the capture rate. After some web search, I found out that I need to send an EOS event to the pipeline (so that the MP4 header could be written properly and the file becomes playable) through a command like: `gst_element_send_event(m_pPipeline, gst_event_new_eos());` where `m_pPipeline` is a pointer to my pipeline element.

However, on my bus I never get a message of type `GST_MESSAGE_EOS` which, in my understanding, means that the EOS message somehow does not travel downstream to my sinks. I tried to add the `message-forward` parameter using `g_object_set (G_OBJECT(m_pPipeline), "message-forward", true, nullptr);` but I observed the same behaviour.

What am I doing wrong here, should the EOS message not directly be sent to the pipeline but to the individual sinks (here `filesink` and `webrtcbin`)?